# Subplots with same axis size having set aspect='equal'

Tags: python, matplotlib

Probably this has already been asked somewhere else but I couldn't find the answer. I'm sorry if this is the case.

How can I get subplots with the same axis sizes?
I need aspect='equal', so that the relative distances are correctly scaled.

This is the code I'm using

```
X_A = [0, 0.4, 0.8, 1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3]
Y_A = [0.3, 0.8, 0, 1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.9]

X_B = [0, 0.4, 0.8, 1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3]
Y_B = [2, 0, 0.8, 3, 3, 2.1, 0.2]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10,10))

ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax1.set_aspect('equal')
ax1.set_title('Dataset A', fontsize=20)

ax1.scatter(X_A, Y_A)

ax2 = plt.subplot(122)
ax2.set_aspect('equal')
ax2.set_title('Dataset B', fontsize=20)

ax2.scatter(X_B, Y_B)
```

I'm getting this:
[image]

There is some simple setting to tune or some math is required?

Comment: couple of things. 1) your indentation is off; 2) you should boil this down to a runnable example that doesn't depend on external data that no one but you has; and 3) the answer to this problem is going to involve inspecting the `bbox` and limits for each Axes object, then doing the math to figure out how much each Axes object's limits need to be expanded or contracted to match the other. Have you tried anything along those lines? How did fall short of what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry for the indentation. I thought to be missing some simple setting that could have solved the problem. I'll try to come up with an example.

Comment: Even if looking for a simple setting it is crucial to provide a [mcve] of the issue. Only having such runnable example available allows people to judge on what the problem is and how to solve it (possibly with a very simple solution indeed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would want to use the `adjustable` argument to `set_aspect`,

```
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable="datalim")
```

This would not let the axes box be adjusted, but rather the limits of the axes.

Complete example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X_A = [0, 0.4, 0.8, 1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3]
Y_A = [0.3, 0.8, 0, 1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.9]

X_B = [0, 0.4, 0.8, 1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3]
Y_B = [2, 0, 0.8, 3, 3, 2.1, 0.2]

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(6,6))

ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable="datalim")
ax.set_title('Dataset A', fontsize=20)

ax.scatter(X_A, Y_A)

ax2.set_aspect('equal', adjustable="datalim")
ax2.set_title('Dataset B', fontsize=20)

ax2.scatter(X_B, Y_B)

ax2.autoscale()

plt.show()
```

producing

[image]